# Why is len() function counting every character in my list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to set a variable to the amount of days that have been booked. I have the days booked stored in a dictionary with the key 'booked_days' and the value is a list of strings.
The problem is when I use the len() function to try and find the amount of things in my list I get a value greater than 100 when the correct output should be around 15-30.

I have tried to loop through the list with a variable that is being incremented with each iteration. This is where I noticed the list has every character in an index. For example every space, comma, and quotation.

```
with open('./' + self.listing + '/' + current_year + '.txt', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        self.annual_revenue += int(row['revenue'])
        if row['month'] == self.month_to_see:
           self.revenue = int(row['revenue'])
           self.occupancy_rate = row['occupancy']
           self.booked_num = len(row['booked_days'])
           print(row)
           print()
           print(row['booked_days'] + '\n')
           print(len(row['booked_days']))
```

This is a print of the dictionary row.

```
OrderedDict([('month', 'August'), ('year', '2019'), ('given_rate', '$225'), ('available_days', "[('27', '$225'), ('28', '$225'), ('29', '$225'), ('30', '$225'), ('31', '$225')]"), ('booked_days', "['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26']"), ('revenue', '5850'), ('rating', '5'), ('occupancy', '83.9')])
```

The expected output is 26 however the actual output is 147. I don't think this code alone will reproduce the problem. However I have no idea where else the problem could be coming from.
The print statements are just for my own debug purposes.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the entry:

```
'booked_days', "['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12',
                 '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23',
                 '24', '25', '26']")
```

`row['booked_days']` is a string, not a list.  Its `len` is the quantity of characters.  You have to convert the string to a list, perhaps by using a JSON reader or other package, rather than your CSV storage.  CSV does not recognize dict and list format for its cells.

For instance, see the text conversion [here](/questions/30650780/python-read-file-with-list-as-list).

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I missed that. Been looking at this program too long. I'll accept you're answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Because `booked_days` is a string representation of a list, and not a list. Calling `len()` on a string will give the number of characters in the string.

If you want to interpret `booked_days` as a list, you will need to alter how you are reading in the CSV file, so your dict actually contains a list instead of a string.

Comment: Quote characters only take up a few pixels, easy enough to miss after looking at the same thing for too long.